# Matrix using rasters

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-10.3

I have two raster files, one for risk areas A,B,C,D and second for land uses rice, crop, soyabean (1,2,3). What is the command that gives number of cells in each risk class that grow 1,2 or 3. I am looking for a matrix like output that has risk categories in rows and land use crops in columns.

Comment: Are you using ArcGIS for Desktop?

Comment: Yes I am. Sorry it was for Arc GIS 10.3

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Combine Tool](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/combine.htm). It will give you a count for each of the combinations from your input rasters.

Comment: It did not help. I was expecting the output raster would have all columns from both rasters. How can I specify that?